# flutter firebase didn't run chrome

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-chrome

[image]
flutter firebase is not working on chrome I have set and put every dependency and plugin in my project

Comment: We need more info to be able to help. Can you share the logs in the terminal where you lunched flutter?

Comment: Please provide code and console log